# Prevent a process to access internet

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, hook, winsock

I'm using Delphi and I would like to code a small "loader" that starts an application and hooks all the Socket APIs so it prevents access to the internet. I have a working hook unit to do that but I still have some questions:

1) Which Windows API's are there that access the internet (Besides Winsock?!)

2) What if an application doesn't use exports and gets addresses dynamically via PEB or GetProcAddress? Is it still possible to hook?

Comment: Or you could just configure Windows Firewall to lock down network access.

Comment: That's why I asked here, cause it is a "programming" question.

Comment: You can configure the Windows Firewall from a program.  Far, far simpler than trying to hook every possible API a program could use to get network access.  (You might also want to put the program inside a job object to prevent it from spawning subprocesses to access the network on its behalf.)

Comment: The idea works, but I disabled the Firewall Service. Thanks for the tips

Comment: Hmm.  You want to block access to the network, but you've disabled the firewall. It's difficult to lock a door when the door has been removed.

Comment: The windows firewall is an optional feature of windows. You can hook the connect function of a process and you have a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are higher level APIs it could use, like WINHTTP or WININET, but you should be able to see what it actually might use by enumerating its static imports.

If the app is trying to hide what it's doing, it might be doing LoadLibrary combined with GetProcAddress(Ex), yes, but you could hook those functions as well.

What exactly is it that you want to prevent this application from doing? - perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: I just don't want an application to connect to a network/internet. Either UDP/TCP/etc... Either http/ftp/etc... If I know the right API functions, I can prevent it with the hooks.